# What does the user icon with the little red up arrow in AD mean?

Tags: active-directory

When looking at the members of a group in AD there are normal members (singe head icon) groups (two heads icon) and then Anonymous Logon / Authenticated Users and Everyone which share an icon which is a single head with a red up arrow.

What does this icon mean?

The icon in question is the user icon but it has a little red up arrow coming out of the user.  It's icon number 34 inside dsuiext.dll:

[image] XP/2003

[image]Vista/7

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The red up arrow indicates a Foreign Security Principal (FSP). This can be used to represent well known FSPs such as *Anonymous Logon* or for users in an external domain.

Technet: [How Security Principals Work](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779144%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: @Tollo: If my answer addresses your question sufficiently please feel free to mark my answer as accepted. :)

Comment: Ahhh I tried to mark it up, but was told I couldn't.  I did not realise that accepted was different until you commented.  Thanks!